# How to keep a movable text inside the window with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, text, shapes

I have a code with text and 2 buttons; bt1 that moves the text left and bt2 that moves the text right. The problem is that I can't figure out how I can keep the text from leaving the window. So in other words how can I keep the text inside the borders of the window? Also, how can I position the text in the center of the window?

Here is the code in question:

```
import javafx.application.Application;import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;import javafx.scene.Scene;import javafx.stage.Stage;import javafx.geometry.Pos;import javafx.scene.control.Button;import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;import javafx.scene.text.Text;import javafx.scene.paint.Color;import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;import java.io.IOException;
```

```
public class Text extends Application {@Overridepublic void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
```

```
    Pane paneText = new Pane();
    Text text = new Text("I'm editable");
    paneText.getChildren().addAll(text);

    HBox paneButton = new HBox(10);
    paneButton.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    Button bt1 = new Button("<");
    Button bt2 = new Button(">");
    paneButton.getChildren().addAll(bt1,bt2);

    HBox paneRadioButton = new HBox(10);
    paneRadioButton.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    RadioButton rbRed = new RadioButton("Red");
    RadioButton rbBlue = new RadioButton("Blue");
    RadioButton rbBlack = new RadioButton("Black");
    RadioButton rbOrange = new RadioButton("Orange");
    RadioButton rbGreen = new RadioButton("Green");

    ToggleGroup gr = new ToggleGroup();
    rbRed.setToggleGroup(gr);
    rbBlue.setToggleGroup(gr);
    rbBlack.setToggleGroup(gr);
    rbOrange.setToggleGroup(gr);
    rbGreen.setToggleGroup(gr);
```

```
paneRadioButton.getChildren().addAll(rbRed,rbBlue,rbBlack,rbOrange,rbGreen);
```

```
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(paneText);
    pane.setTop(paneButtons);
    pane.setBottom(paneRadioButtons);

    bt1.setOnAction(e -> text.setX(text.getX() - 10));
    bt2.setOnAction(e -> text.setX(text.getX() + 10));

    rbRed.setOnAction(e -> text.setFill(Color.RED));
    rbBlue.setOnAction(e -> text.setFill(Color.BLUE));
    rbBlack.setOnAction(e -> text.setFill(Color.BLACK));
    rbOrange.setOnAction(e -> text.setFill(Color.ORANGE));
    rbGreen.setOnAction(e -> text.setFill(Color.GREEN));


    Scene scene = new Scene(paneeli,400, 250);
    stage.setTitle("Text");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

```
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. might be but unreadable due to broken code formatting ;) Edit and make sure there are at least 4 leading spaces on every line and no tabs

Answer (score 1):

**restrinct  translation with conditions**

For the left side is easy . It's just if(x>0){....} . But the right side is a little bit tricky . You need to know the current width of the translated node and the width of its parent . In this approach the condition works even if the parent is stretched , but is not implemented for the opposite ( parent width is reduced )

[image: javafx text node]

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        var text = new Text("hola");
        var boundWidth = text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        var left = new Button("left");
        var right = new Button("right");
        var anchorPane = new AnchorPane(left, right, text);

        left.setOnAction((t) -> {
            if (text.getTranslateX() > 0) {
                text.setTranslateX(text.getTranslateX() - 10);
            }

        });
        right.setOnAction((t) -> {
            if (text.getTranslateX() + 10 <= anchorPane.getWidth() - boundWidth) {
                text.setTranslateX(text.getTranslateX() + 10);

            }
        });
        
     
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(left, 10d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(right, 10d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(text, 30d);

        var scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 120, 50);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```